# Loosing precision when converting to general type in excel

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have excel sheet which has numeric, text, general values.

I need to convert all those to general format before loading to DB.

Below is my code,

```
xlsApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
xlsWorkbook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(sPath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
xlsWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlsWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range range = xlsWorksheet.UsedRange;
range.NumberFormat = "@";
```

While converting to general/text format I am loosing precision on cells.

Eg: Actual value of my cell is 3.23117700156163.

After converting to general, value is 3.231178

Please help

Comment: Your code does not show where the conversion happens. Also: What is the format of your DB column?

Comment: Is youtr problem with the display in excel, or is it a problem of incorrect data in the DB?

Comment: Problem is with display

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the formatting of the cell in Excel.

"General" may not deliver what you want.

When I paste the value from your post into an Excel cell that is formatted with "General", I get

3.231177002

Excel has 15 digits to express a number. You can format the cell to show up to 15 digits. They can be either before or after the decimal marker. Anything with more than 15 digits will be rounded or filled in with zeroes.

Comment: Is there a way to take the values without rounding off? I need to load those values to DB without rounding off. I am using OleDB connection to read the excel values after conversion to General format.

Comment: Excel can only store numbers with 15 digit precision. Anything more needs to be stored as text or rounded. 15 digits is a LOT! If you need more than that, precision should not be an issue. Who cares if it is 123456789012340 or 123456789012349. In that magnitude, what difference does the last digit make?